# Given an Array of strings, compute recursively (no loops) whether or not the Array contains the string "milk" somewhere

Tags: java

I am getting an int i=0 and an array strings that contains a given set of words, and am suppose to return a boolean value based if the world milk is in the array?

```
public boolean gotMilk(int i, String[] strings) {
  boolean test=true;
  char ch=strings.chatAt(i);
  if(ch!='m'){
    test=false;
  }
  return test;
}
```

this is what I have now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZj7v.png)

Comment: Typo charAt() instead of chatAt().

Comment: oh man, you are right I can't believe I missed that. fixed it but still no luck

Comment: You'd need to access a single element in the array.

Comment: A loop is necessary.

Comment: the rules don't allow me to use a loop, now I am looking at how to select a single element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem "recursively" you need to have gotMilk keep calling itself (incrementing the index i to the next value in the array). You immediately stop and return true if you find milk; otherwise you continue to the next item... unless you run out of items, in which case you return false!

Hope that helps!

```
public boolean gotMilk(int i, String[] strings) {
  if (strings == null) return false;
  if ((i < 0) || (i >= strings.length)) return false;
  if ("milk".equals(strings[i])) {
    return true;  // If THIS element is milk, return true
  } else if (i + 1 >= strings.length) {
    return false; // If we've reached the end of the array, then we've struck out return false;
  } else {
    return gotMilk(i+1, strings); // Otherwise continue recursively to next item in array
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much this helped me understand how to move to the next element without a loop.

Comment: `if ("milk".equals(strings[i]))` may throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since your method does not check the validity of parameter `i`. Also, `else if (i + 1 >= strings.length)` may throw `NullPointerException` if `strings` is null. You also don't check the validity of that parameter.

Comment: Yeah I agree I didn't get into validity checking because he wasn't doing any in his example, and it looked like a homework-assignment kind of situation rather than a piece of production software. I kept it simple to address the core "ask" of how to solve with recursion.

Comment: I've added the validity checks in, in case that is useful for a more robust answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
public static boolean gotMilk(int i, String[] strings) {
    if (strings == null || strings.length == 0) return false;
    if ("milk".equals(strings[i])) return true;
    if (i == strings.length - 1) return false;
    return gotMilk(i+1, strings);
}
```

To test:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] input = {"abc","def","ghi","milk"};
    System.out.println(gotMilk(0,input));
}
```

Note that this perform equals check which mean the string must be exactly to be "milk". If you want to check whether each element contains "milk" or not, using contains instead.

Comment: Why 'if (strings == null || strings.length == 0) will throw NullPointerException'. In runtime, when using || in if condition, if the first condition is true then it will not perform check for second condition.

Comment: You'are right for i is negative, it can included in the first check.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive method must first contain a condition that terminates the recursion.
If the condition is true, the method returns.
If the condition is false, the method calls itself with different parameters than those it received.

Your recursive method accepts two parameters. The current array index and the array. For each recursive call of the method, you increment the index.

The terminating condition is whether the element of the array at the current index is "milk".

Here is the code.
Note that the method also checks the validity of its parameters.

```java
public class Recurses {
    private static boolean gotMilk(int ndx, String[] words) {
        boolean hasGot = false;
        if (words != null  &&  ndx >= 0  &&  ndx < words.length) {
            if ("milk".equals(words[ndx])) {
                hasGot = true;
            }
            else {
                hasGot = gotMilk(ndx + 1, words);
            }
        }
        return hasGot;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("gotMilk(0, [\"water\", \"soda\", \"juice\"] -> " + gotMilk(0, new String[]{"water", "soda", "juice"}));
        System.out.println("gotMilk(0, [\"milk\", \"water\", \"soda\", \"juice\"] -> " + gotMilk(0, new String[]{"milk", "water", "soda", "juice"}));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much this helped me understand how to test for empty strings.

Answer (score -1):

[charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) is a method of `String` class but not of a String Array. So you have to loop through the array and check the character of each String like this:

```
public boolean gotMilk(int i, String[] strings) {
    boolean test = false;
    for (String str : strings) {
        Character ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (ch == 'm') {
            test = true;
        }
    }
    return test;
}
```

Also, if you want to check for "milk", you have to check for the entire String instead of the 1st character. Checking only 1st character will give you wrong results when you have another string starting with 'm' Eg: man will also return true in above code. Correct way would be:

```
public boolean gotMilk(String[] strings) {
    boolean test = false;
    for (String str : strings) {
        if ("milk".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
            test = true;
        }
    }
    return test;
}
```

Another simple way:

```
public boolean gotMilk(String[] strings) {
        return Arrays.asList(strings).contains("milk");
}
```

Comment: `chatAt(i)` is **not** a method of `String` class.

Comment: Class `java.lang.String` does not contain a method named `chatAt`. It contains a method named [charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-)

Comment: @rajeshk It is not `chatAt`, it is `charAt`. Check the spelling!

Comment: My bad. Didn't even realise. Thank you so much